# Can we split the user if they have a same profile

Tags: apex, trigger, community, administration

1. I Created three communities and add a Custom Profile "CommunityCommunityProfile". I created Users with this Profile.
2. Now Problem is all the users with this profile are login into  all the communities. i want to login User1 for Community1
   and User2 for Community2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can create permission sets for specific users and assign them under specific community. Please don't enable the Profile "CommunityCommunityProfile" under any community.

Here are the steps:-

1. Create three permission set for three users.
2. Go to Setup > All Communities
3. Click Manage next to the community name.
4. Click Administration | Members.
5. Select Permission Set for community.
6. Click Save.

Repeat the step from 2 to 6 for assigning permission set for each community.

Let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: If we create permission set for one community. If I create 100 communities what about this. And if we assign permission set to one Community User and with the same permission we can create another permission set they have a permission to see another community.

Comment: are you sure, you want 100 communities?